# Bash: How can I echo a string if a `cat myfile` command returns nothing?

Tags: bash, awk

showErrors.sh:

```
echo 'Logfile 1'
cat /var/log/logfile1
echo 'Logfile 2'
cat /var/log/logfile2
```

I'd like to `echo 'No errors found!'` if the file is empty.

I've tried (guessed) `cat /var/log/logfile1 || echo 'No errors found!'` and `(cat /var/log/logfile1) || echo 'No errors found!'` to no avail.

So here I am.  Thank you!

Comment: So like `if [[ -e file && ! -s file ]]; then echo "no errors found"; fi`?

Comment: I should have added that I know this would be achievable with an if block.  I guess my question REALLY should have been "is it possible to chain commands until you get an output".  Similar to how in PHP you could do `echo $notdeclared ?? $alsonotdeclared ?? $declared;` and it would output the value of the last variable.

Comment: Yes, you should have. So... you want `[[ -e file && ! -s file ]] && cat /var/log/logfile1 || echo 'No errors found!'`? You can also write your own `cat`-ish tool that would return nonzero in case the file is empty.

Comment: What do you want output if the file doesn't exist? What if it exists but is a directory? What if it exists but isn't readable?

Comment: @KamilCuk the problem with that is that you'd get `No errors found!` output in addition to partial file contents if some failure occurred while `cat`-ing the file, e.g. someone killed the process. That's because `stuff && foo || bar` isn't a ternary expression despite looking like one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
grep '^' file || echo 'No errors found!'
```

Unlike `cat`, that `grep` will exit with a failure status if `file` is empty (or doesn't exist or is unreadable, etc.). You can change it to `grep '.'` if you want it to treat a file with all empty lines the same as an empty file:

```
$ printf '' | grep '^' || echo "is empty"
is empty
$ printf '' | grep '.' || echo "is empty"
is empty
$ printf '\n' | grep '^' || echo "is empty"

$ printf '\n' | grep '.' || echo "is empty"
is empty
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check that a file is empty using `wc -l`, so you get:

```
file1_empty=$(wc -l /var/log/logfile1)

if [ file1_empty -eq 0 ]
then
echo "No errors found"
else
cat /var/log/logfile1
fi
```

Good luck

Comment: That doesn't check that the file is empty, it checks that it doesn't contain any newlines. Try `printf 'foo' > file` and  then `wc -l file` will output `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it done in a single `gnu awk` command:

```sh
cd /var/log/

awk 'BEGINFILE {print FILENAME} 1;
ENDFILE {if (!FNR) print "No errors found!"}' logfile1 logfile2
```

This can be extended to print any number of files by giving more filenames in argument list to `awk`.

**How it works:**

- `BEGINFILE` this block executes at the start of each file processing
- `ENDFILE` this block executes at the end of each file processing
- `1`: prints each record
  = `!FNR`: Condition will be true of input file is empty